# Два заголовочных файла содержащих друг друга

Tags: c++

Есть 2 класса, которые находятся в разных заголовочных файлах. Мне нужно объявить в первом классе ссылку на второй класс, а во втором ссылку на первый.
Если делать такую цикличность, то в каком-то из классов выдается ошибка "type name expected".

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Проблема понятна.

Что происходит:

- c1.cpp: включает c1.h
- c1.h: устанавливает include guard: `#ifndef C1_H #define C1_H`
- c1.h: подключает c2.h
- c2.h: устанавливает свой include guard и подключает c1.h
- читается c1.h, но из-за include guard `#ifndef C1_H` не срабатывает, весь контент игнорируется
- код в c2.h не видит классов, определённых в c1.h

---

Если вам нужно сделать лишь ссылку на класс, вам не обязательно подключать header. Попробуйте так:

```
// c1.h

// предварительное объявление, его должно быть достаточно
class c2;

class c1
{
    c2* p;
    // остальной код класса
};
```

А вот в c1.cpp уже нужно будет реально подключать c2.h.

При этом любой код из класса, который разыменовывает указатель на `c2`, должен уйти в c1.cpp.

Comment: Шикарно! Спасибо

Comment: @T2skler: Пожалуйста!

Comment: А методы класса c2 можно вызывать по ссылке? У меня вот ошибка 'ShootPlayer' is not a member of 'CGameController', because the type is not yet defined

Comment: @T2skler: в c1.h нет, но если вы перенесёте этот код в c1.cpp, то да.